# Unit Testing: Angular4: Jasmine: Response is undefined in subscribe when control returns from fake service methods

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am mocking a service by creating its mock class in spec file. In my component there is a function which calls data service. When spec runs it successfully goes to mock method but does not return the data, i.e., content inside observable.of.
The error I am getting is 'Expected undefined to be truthy.' for my it case.

spec file

---

```
import { BaseRequestOptions, Http, HttpModule, Response, ResponseOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { AddserviceCenterRepairAuthorityComponent } from './add-serviceCenter-repair-authority.component';
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SelectItem, MultiSelectModule, CalendarModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { CoreUIModule } from 'core-ui';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { scooterRepairService } from '../services/scooterRepair.service';
import { StorageService } from 'core-shared/core.service';
import { serviceCenterRepairAdd } from '../models/serviceCenter-repair-add.model';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { IMissingscooterRepair } from '../models/missing-scooter-repair';
import { serviceCenterRepairRecord } from '../models/serviceCenter-repair-record.model';
import { RepairClass } from '../models/repairClass.model';
import { RepairCode } from '../models/repairCode.model';
import { serviceCenterRepairSearch } from '../models/serviceCenter-repair-search.model';
import { scooterRepairSearch } from '../models/scooter-repair-search.model';
import { scooterRepairRecord } from '../models/scooter-repair-record.model';



fdescribe('AddserviceCenterRepairAuthorityComponent', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AddserviceCenterRepairAuthorityComponent>;
    let de: DebugElement;
    let el: HTMLElement;
    let router: Router;
    let comp: AddserviceCenterRepairAuthorityComponent;

    class MockscooterRepairService {
        headers: Headers = new Headers();
        private help = '';
        private scooterRepairAuthorityApiurl = 'http://localhost:3000/scooterRepairAuthority';

        constructor() {
            this.headers.append('appuser', 'devnxd');
        }

        public submitserviceCenterRepair(serviceCenterRepairAddRecord): Observable<any> {
            if (serviceCenterRepairAddRecord.hasOwnProperty()) {
                return Observable.throw('Error occurred, please try again');
            } else {
                return Observable.of(
                    {
                        'isSuccess': true, 'results': [{ 'recordId': 1 }], 'recordId': 1
                    });


            }
        }


        clone(object: any) {
            return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
        }

        public getscooterInitials(): Observable<SelectItem[]> {

            return Observable.of(
                {

                });
        }

        public getThresholdValues(isAmountOnly: boolean): Observable<SelectItem[]> {
            return Observable.of(
                {

                });
        }
        public getRepairClassItems(): Observable<SelectItem[]> {
            return Observable.of(
                {

                });
        }
        public getRepairCodeItems(): Observable<SelectItem[]> {
            return Observable.of(
                {

                });
        }
        public getPercentageApprovalItems(): Observable<SelectItem[]> {
            return Observable.of(
                {

                });
        }


        public getUnitCountItems(scooterInitials: string[]): Observable<SelectItem[]> {
            return Observable.of(
                {

                });
        }

        public getscooterClassItems(scooterInitials: string[]): Observable<SelectItem[]> {
            return Observable.of(
                {

                });
        }

        public getFacilityItems(): Observable<SelectItem[]> {
            return Observable.of(
                {

                });
        }


        public searchscooterRepairs(scooterRepairSearch: scooterRepairSearch): Observable<scooterRepairRecord[]> {
            return Observable.of(
                {

                });
        }


        public searchserviceCenterRepairs(strFacility: string[], strStatusCode: string[], strthreshold: string[], lastUpdatedDate: Date,
            insertDate: Date, effectiveStartDate: Date, effectiveEndDate: Date) {
            return Observable.of(
                {

                });
        }



        public submitscooterRepair(scooterRepairRecord: scooterRepairRecord, isValidated: boolean = true): Observable<any> {
            return Observable.of(
                {

                });
        }
        public searchMissingscooterRepairs(): Observable<IMissingscooterRepair> {
            return Observable.of(
                {

                });
        }

        private getDefaultHeaders(): Headers {
            const headers: Headers = new Headers();
            // headers.append('appuser', this.auth.user.userName);
            headers.append('appuser', 'devvws');
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            //   headers.append('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
            // headers.append('Pragma', 'no-cache');
            return headers;
        }



        private handleError(error: Response) {
            return Observable.throw(error.statusText || 'Server error');
        }

        private extractData(res: Response, isResultOnly: boolean = true) {
            const data = res.json();
            console.log(data);
            // const data = res.json(); // This will be used when actual service calling
            if (data.isSuccess) {
                return isResultOnly ? data.results : data;
            } else if (data.isException && data.errors.length > 0) {
                this.handleError(data.errors[0]);
            }
            return {};
        }
        convertFeatureListToNGPrimeDropdownOptions(list: any, labelKey, valueKey): SelectItem[] {
            const data = this.clone(list);
            const options: SelectItem[] = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                this.changeKeyName(data[i], labelKey, 'label');
                this.changeKeyName(data[i], valueKey, 'value');
                options.push(data[i]);
            }
            return options;
        }

        private changeKeyName(obj: any, oldKey: string, newKey: string): any {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(oldKey)) {
                obj[newKey] = obj[oldKey];
                delete obj[oldKey];
            }
            return obj;
        }

    }

    // async beforeEach
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        class RouterStub {
            navigateByUrl(url: string) { return url; }
        }




        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [AddserviceCenterRepairAuthorityComponent], // declare the test component
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
            providers: [scooterRepairService, MockBackend, StorageService,
                BaseRequestOptions,
                {
                    provide: Http,
                    useFactory: (backend, options) => new Http(backend, options),
                    deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
                },
                { provide: scooterRepairService, useClass: MockscooterRepairService },
            ],
            imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule, FormsModule, MultiSelectModule, CalendarModule, CoreUIModule, RouterTestingModule]

        })
            .compileComponents();  // compile template and css
    }));

    // synchronous beforeEach -- used if component is having external templates
    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AddserviceCenterRepairAuthorityComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('component is created', () => {
        expect(comp).toBeTruthy();
    });

    xit('unsuccessful should be true when serviceCenterRepairAddRecord is empty object', () => {

        comp.serviceCenterRepairAddRecord = <serviceCenterRepairAdd>{};
        const recordAddedSuccessfully = comp.onAddserviceCenterRepairClick();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(recordAddedSuccessfully).toBe(2);
    });


    it('unsuccessful should be true when serviceCenterRepairAddRecord is not empty object', () => {

        comp.serviceCenterRepairAddRecord = <serviceCenterRepairAdd>{
            'facilityId': 1, 'statusCode': '200', 'thresholdAmount': 432,
            'effectiveStartDate': new Date(), 'effectiveEndDate': new Date(), 'builtEndDate': new Date()
        };
        comp.unsuccessful = 0;
        const recordAddedSuccessfully = comp.onAddserviceCenterRepairClick();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(recordAddedSuccessfully).toBeTruthy();
    });


    xit('on cancel scooter repair click', () => {
        const spy = spyOn((<any>comp).router, 'navigateByUrl');
        comp.onCancelserviceCenterRepairClick();

        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('cra');

    });
});
```

---

component.ts

---

```
onAddserviceCenterRepairClick() {
        this.scooterRepairService.submitserviceCenterRepair(this.serviceCenterRepairAddRecord).subscribe(
            response => this.submitedSuccess = response.recordId
            ,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
            () => {
                if (this.submitedSuccess === -1) {
                    alert('Record cannot be added');
                    this.unsuccessful = 2;
                } else {
                    this.unsuccessful = 1;
                    this.router.navigate(['cra'], { queryParams: { from: 'serviceCenterRepairSubmit' } });
                }
            }

        );

    }
```

---

When control returns from the fake service class it should have the object returned from Observable.of. But in response variable in above component.ts code is undefined.

Please help..!

Answer (score 0):

Your returning an **array of objects** as per your return type in the method. But you are returning **only one object** which caused you this error

```
return Observable.of([{

                   }]);
```

Comment: even when I use
 return Observable.of(
                    {
                        'isSuccess': true
                    });

I am having the same error

Comment: even when I use return Observable.of( { 'isSuccess': true }); I am having the same error

Comment: are you available in teamviewer?

Answer (score 0):

Response will always be empty since the original call was done to mock class. For unit test check the value of this.submitedSuccess which is an instance variable. Check if its equal to -1 or 1 sent from the fake Observable.